# Using NetLogo with OpenMOLE

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to get started with OpenMOLE, in order to run NetLogo models. I am currently having trouble with getting OpenMOLE to run any NetLogo model, even the fire.nlogo example on their website. I was wondering if the problem could be that OpenMOLE can't find the NetLogo application. I have tried putting the NetLogo.jar file in the same directory, but that doesn't seem to help. Where should NetLogo be in relation to OpenMOLE for it to run NetLogo models?

This is the error I am getting when I try to run any NetLogo model:

```
<console>:243: error: type mismatch;
found   : Unit
required: org.openmole.core.workflow.puzzle.PuzzleBuilder
}
```

Comment: what version of OM are you using? could you try with the latest RC available from the website?

Comment: Hi, I have only just seen this - need to turn on my notifications! I basically joined the OpenMole users mailing list, and posted the question on there. There was a problem with the version I was using, and they gave me a newer one. In case anyone else is reading this and has any OpenMole questions, I highly recommend posting on their mailing list, as they are incredibly helpful!